# Proving u-substitution the hard way -- use only definition of integration with partitions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

I am trying to prove integration by substitution, i.e. for $f:[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $\phi: [c,d] \rightarrow [a,b]$ continuous on $[c,d]$ and $\mathscr{C}^1$ on $(c,d)$. Then define $\phi(a) = c$ and $\phi(b) = d$. Then $$\int_c^d f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u = \int_a^bf\left(\phi(t)\right)\phi'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

This is pretty easy to prove if you use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (proof wiki has a succinct one). However, I want to try to prove it using only the definition of integration with partitions (Riemann) without using other facts.

To make it easier, assume $\phi'(x)>0$ so that it's a bijection.

I know that it is going to involve some tricky $\epsilon$ work, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Obviously I want to find some partition P of $[a,b]$ and then think about $\phi(P)$, but that doesn't get me far.

Comment: Did you mean $\phi'(x) >0$?

Comment: Can you use the implicit function theorem (to show that ${ 1 \over (\phi^{-1})'(t)} = \phi'(\phi^{-1}(t))$).

Comment: yes, I did mean $\phi'(x)$. 
And I could use the implicit function theorem, but I'm trying to do it directly by constructing partitions. Unless there's a way to apply the IFT that I'm missing?

Comment: Well, for example, $(\sup_{x \in [a,b]} f(x))(b-a) = (\sup_{x \in [\phi^{-1}(a),\phi^{-1}(b)]} f(\phi(t)))({b-a \over \phi^{-1}(b)-\phi^{-1}(a)} )(\phi^{-1}(b)-\phi^{-1}(a))$. For 'small enough' partitions,  ${b-a \over \phi^{-1}(b)-\phi^{-1}(a)} \approx {1 \over (\phi^{-1})'(a)} = \phi'(a)$.